# Freemarker email footer style not consistent in all email clients

Tags: html, css, freemarker

I have user Freemarker templates to implement the email design.  I keep having issue where the header and footer.ftl templates styling is not consistent in different email clients, especially outlook.  I'm so tired of making css changes to accommodate any new changes requested by the product owner. In outlook the client logo expands too much which causes the other fields to shift. Below is what the template should look like [image]
but in outlook it looks like this [image]

Is there a better solution to this? Are there any better libraries than Freemarker?  Emails are sent to different devices and email clients. I need something that can adjust accordingly. 
Thanks!, 
 style="background-color:transparent;">

```
          <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><td align="center" width="685" style=" width:685px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent;" valign="top" ><![endif]-->
        <div class="col num12" style="min-width: 320px;max-width: 685px;width: 685px;width: calc(36500% - 249340px);background-color: transparent;">
          <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--><div style="border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent;"><!--<![endif]-->
            <div style="background-color: transparent; display: inline-block!important; width: 100% !important; ">

             <div style="border-collapse: collapse;display: table;background-color:transparent;min-width: 320px;max-width: 685px;width: 685px;width: calc(36500% - 249340px);">
      <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td style="background-color:transparent;" align="center"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 575px;"><tr class="layout-full-width" style="background-color:transparent;"><![endif]-->

          <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]><td align="center" width="383" style=" width:383px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent; " valign="top"><![endif]-->
        <div class="col num8" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: top;min-width: 340px;max-width: 396px;">
          <div style="background-color: #646c82; width: 100% !important; text-align: right;">
          <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--><div class="container" style="text-align: right;"><!--<![endif]-->
            <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;">
              <img alt="Image" title="Company Logo" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;" src="${contextUrl}/common/images/ht_logo_white.png">
             </div>

          <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--></div><!--<![endif]-->
          </div>
        </div>
          <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td><td align="center" width="192" style=" width:192px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; border-top: 0px solid transparent; border-left: 0px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; border-right: 0px solid transparent;" valign="top"><![endif]-->
        <div class="col num4" style="display: table-cell;vertical-align: top;max-width: 300px;min-width: 168px; vertical-align: middle;">
          <div style="background-color: transparent; width: 100% !important; color: #646c82">
          <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--><div style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; padding: 0px;"><!--<![endif]-->

             <p style="margin: 0;font-size: 10px;text-align: center">
                <strong><span style="color: #646C82; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Ergopoint &copy; 2011-2018</span></strong><br>
             </p>
                <p style="margin: 0;font-size: 10px;text-align: center; font-weight: 400; line-height: 5px;">&nbsp;</p>
                <p style="margin: 0;font-size: 10px;font-weight: 100; text-align: center">
                    <strong><span style="color: #646C82; font-size: 10px; font-weight: 400;">Humantech, Inc.</span></strong>
                </p>
                <p style="margin: 0;font-size: 10px;font-weight: 100;text-align: center">
                    <strong><span style="color: #646C82; font-size: 10px; font-weight: 400;">1161 Oak Valley Drive</span></strong>
                </p>
                <p style="margin: 0;font-size: 10px; font-weight: 100; text-align: center">
                    <strong><span style="color: #646C82; font-size: 10px; font-weight: 400;">Ann Arbor, MI&nbsp;</span></strong>
                </p>

          <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--></div><!--<![endif]-->
          </div>
        </div>
      <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
    </div>


         </div>
       <!--[if (!mso)&(!IE)]><!--></div><!--<![endif]-->
     </div>
   <!--[if (mso)|(IE)]></tr></table></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you send the email to different email clients I suggest to you use tables to make the e-mail, they are more reliable to show the email like expected. About your code see that [link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) some properties not have support of all email clients and I believe you can simplify the code that way:

```
 <div style="width: 650px;">
   <div style="width: 100%; background-color: #646c82; text-align: center; height: 25px; color: #fff;">HEADER</div>
   <div style="width: 100%;text-align: center; padding: 10px 0">BODY</div>
   <div style="width: 100%;text-align: center; height: 25px; color: #646c82;">FOOTER</div>
 </div>
```

If you use tables:

```
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="650">
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%; background-color: #646c82; text-align: center; height: 25px; color: #fff;">
          HEADER
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 30px">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%;text-align: center;">
          BODY
        </td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="height: 30px">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%;text-align: center; height: 25px; color: #646c82;">
          FOOTER
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I did not testing this codes, this is an idea what i would do.

I hope helped.